# Cannot find module 'rxjs/operators' while creating new project in angular-cli

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-cli

when i am trying to create new project in angular-cli by terminal using command

```
Mani-MacBook-Air:angular-project manigupta$ ng new controlgame
```

**showing error:**

```
module.js:487
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'rxjs/operators'

at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/logger/indent.js:10:21)
at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
```

Please let me know what I should do to create new project in angular-cli

**Answer:**

I uninstalled the angular-cli then install with latest version using following command

sudo npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

npm cache verify

sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

('sudo' is only for mac/linux user)

Comment: Please note that `angularjs` refers to angular 1.x and `angular` refers to angular version 2 and later.

Comment: are you using `angular-cli` ?check this link for guide `https://github.com/angular/angular-cli` if you are using angular cli . it creates a package.json inside your project folder by default .you have to change directory to your project folder and then  run `npm update` if rxjs is already in package.json

Comment: yeah..I m using

Comment: @ManiGupta check this link https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please include the full CLI command you are using and also at what point you are getting the error (at run time or at another point).

Comment: @Igor I agree with you , this error can happen when the rxjs package is not installed and `ng serve` is being called

Comment: When the angular-cli creates a new project all the `rxjs` dependencies will already have been created in the `package.json` file, all you have to do is run `npm i` if you opted not to download the dependencies when you created the project.

Comment: yeah if you opr for `--skip install` during project creation then you have to manually install the packages

Comment: are you trying to import something from 'rxjs/operators' in your code? what is the stack trace of the error? or at least the relevant information of it. Could you add the output of `ng -v`?

Comment: Mani-MacBook-Air:~ manigupta$ ng -v
module.js:487
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'rxjs/operators'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/logger/indent.js:10:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version of the cli: `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest` . Also update your question with the relevant information, do not put it in the comments where it can be easily missed and the formatting is confusing to read.

Comment: Thanks@ Niladari, Igor....
I uninstalled the angular-cli then install with latest version using following command

sudo npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache verify

sodo npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

('sodo' is only for mac/linux user)

Comment: @Igor, you should probably put that as an answer, as I'm pretty sure that is what the solution was, and for future people they may not see the comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you are using the latest version of the cli

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Comment: exactly `operators` is not a module

Comment: but the question is about creating a new module not while using

Comment: @Sajeetharan op never mentioned something about creating a new module

Comment: Actually, with Angular5 there is now an `rxjs/operators`, and it is the proper way to use it with 5+